# How to stub base class method that takes multiple arguments in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to test that instance of ChildClass calls something_interesting while omitting call to BaseClass.my_method

```
class BaseClass
  def my_method *args, &block
  end
end

class ChildClass < BaseClass
  def my_method first_arg, second_arg
    something_interesting
    super first_arg, second_arg
  end
end
```

If I write my test like this:

```
subject = ChildClass.new
subject.should_receive :something_interesting
BaseClass.any_instance.stub :my_method
subject.my_method
```

I get error:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Any ideas why is that so? How to stub it out correctly?

Comment: I would move "something interesting" to its own method and test it separately. (Another fun option that removes the need for stubbing is to monkey patch BaseClass.)

Comment: @froderik it is in separate method. i just need to make sure that my_method calls it.

Comment: Aha - I would rely on integration tests for that. I tend to avoid mocking and stubbing as much as possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could stub `super`:

```
describe ChildClass do
  it 'calls something_interesting' do
    subject.should_receive(:something_interesting)
    subject.stub(:super)
    subject.my_method 'a', 'b'
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, are you sure this works? It makes sense to me and it's simple and elegant but I'm trying to use it in a spec (`task.stub(:super=>false)`) but the subject of the spec seems to keep using the real method, not the stubbed one. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: No, I'm afraid you're right. The test passes but the stub doesn't work; the method in BaseClass is called nevertheless. Feel free to downvote.

Answer (score 3):

I had to play with this a bit. This may be silly but I think it is a rather explicit way to do it (without stubbing):

```
require 'rspec'

class BaseClass
  def my_method *args, &block
    raise 'hell'
  end
end

class ChildClass < BaseClass
  def my_method first_arg, second_arg
    something_interesting
    super first_arg, second_arg
  end

  def something_interesting
  end
end


describe ChildClass do
    it "should work" do
        class BaseClass
            def my_method *args, &block
            end
        end
        subject = ChildClass.new
        subject.should_receive :something_interesting
        subject.my_method 'two', 'args'
    end
end
```

Monkey patching may be a bit evil but is a nice tool to have when testing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no connection between intances `BaseClass.any_instance` and `ChildClass.new`, you've just stubed method in instance and expecting stubbing in another instance.

Second, testing is not meant to test internal parts of object. If you're dealing with `BaseClass'` object, do test on its methods. If you're dealing with `ChildClass'` object, check everything that this object can come up with, don't go deep inside.

Comment: "there's no connection between intances" good, I understand then why it throws that argument error. "don't go deep inside" -> and that is why I want to stub it out, still unsure how to do that though.